How to draw lines with a color gradient in Pygame?
I wish to draw a sequence of lines with a color gradient, so that the color fades from bright white to either black or fully transparent:

Ideally, pygame.draw.lines() would accept a list as the color argument with one color for each vertex, or two colors for the end points. Seeing as there isn't anything like that in the API, how do I implement my own gradient line drawing function?
The line can be one pixel wide and doesn't have to be anti-aliased, but I'd rather there'd be a better way than implementing Bresenham's algorithm using pygame.gfxdraw.pixel().

Nope.  pygame is a convenient package, but it's not that high-end.  There are add-ons to do it, however:  https://www.pygame.org/project-gradients-307-.html

It's certainly possible, but PyGame offers no ready-made solution.
In example below, I present a GradientLine class.   This works by calculating the colour-steps from the original colour through to the final colour.  Using the stepped-colour for each part of the line.
It assumes there will be less colours than than the count of the pixels, and optimises accordingly. This is a reasonable assumption because most consumer displays:

support only 256 different steps per colour channel
typically have many more than 256 pixels of screen resolution

So the class first generates the list of pixels that would make-up the line on-screen.  As the algorithm steps through the pixels, it looks for significant (i.e.: visible) changes in the colour.  If a colour change is found, a line segment is stored and a new segment started.  But if the colour-change is not significant, that pixel is ignored in favour of creating a longer single-coloured line.

So each gradient-line is a list of single-colour line segments.   If your 1000 pixel line only changes colour 15 times, we'd expect 15 line segments, each 66 pixels long.   Drawing these 15 lines is much faster than 1000 pixels of individual colour.
The code does these colour calculations in floating point.  This ensures the cumulative, but tiny variations in colour are not lost to rounding and/or truncation.
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 800 
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800
BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
RED      = (220,   0,   0)
GREEN    = (  0, 220,   0)
BLUE     = (  0,   0, 220)
ORANGE   = (255, 165,   0)  


def clamp( point ):
    """ Ensure the point is inside the window """
    x, y = point
    x = max( 0, x )
    x = min( WINDOW_WIDTH-1, x )
    y = max( 0, y )
    y = min( WINDOW_HEIGHT-1, y )
    return x, y


def getLinePath( start_pos, end_pos ):
    """ Using Bresenham's Line algorithm, get a list of all the points
        along a straight-line path from the start to the end (inclusive).
        Note that this includes diagonal movement """

    # clamp range to window
    x0, y0 = clamp( start_pos )
    x1, y1 = clamp( end_pos )
    points = []

    # ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Algorithm_for_integer_arithmetic
    dx = abs(x1 - x0)
    if x0 < x1:
        sx = 1
    else:
        sx = -1
    dy = -abs(y1 - y0)
    if y0 < y1:
        sy = 1
    else:
        sy = -1
    error = dx + dy
    
    while True:
        points.append( ( x0,y0 ) )
        if x0 == x1 and y0 == y1:
            break
        e2 = 2 * error
        if e2 >= dy:
            if x0 == x1:
                break
            error = error + dy
            x0 = x0 + sx
        if e2 <= dx:
            if y0 == y1:
                break
            error = error + dx
            y0 = y0 + sy

    return points



class GradientLine:
    def __init__( self, start_point, end_point, start_colour, end_colour, thickness:int=1 ):
        self.lines   = []
        self.width   = thickness

        line_pixels  = getLinePath( start_point, end_point )
        pixel_count  = float( len( line_pixels ) )
        red_step     = float( end_colour[0] - start_colour[0] ) / pixel_count 
        green_step   = float( end_colour[1] - start_colour[1] ) / pixel_count
        blue_step    = float( end_colour[2] - start_colour[2] ) / pixel_count

        red   = float( start_colour[0] )
        green = float( start_colour[1] )
        blue  = float( start_colour[2] )

        # It is too inefficient to continually draw a huge whack of pixels
        # So Identify a bunch of line-segments that are the same colour
        start_point = None
        for pixel in line_pixels:
            if ( start_point == None ):
                start_point = pixel
                start_red, start_green, start_blue = ( red, green, blue )
            else:
                # calculate the next colour
                # if that colour significantly different, output a line segment
                if ( abs( start_red - red )     > 1.0 or \
                     abs( start_green - green ) > 1.0 or \
                     abs( start_blue - blue )   > 1.0 ):
                    colour  = ( int( start_red ), int( start_green ), int( start_blue ) )
                    self.lines.append( ( start_point, pixel, colour ) )
                    start_point = None

            # crawl the gradient
            red   += red_step
            green += green_step
            blue  += blue_step

    def draw( self, surface:pygame.Surface ):
        """ Draw a line from start to end, changing colour along the way """
        for segment in self.lines:
            point_a, point_b, colour = segment
            pygame.draw.line( surface, colour, point_a, point_b, self.width )




###
### MAIN
###
pygame.init()
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Gradient Line")


# Define some Gradient Lines
grad_lines = []
grad_lines.append( GradientLine( ( 0,0 ),    ( 799,799 ),  BLUE,  ORANGE, 5 ) )
grad_lines.append( GradientLine( ( 0,399 ),  ( 799,399 ),  RED,   GREEN,  5 ) )
grad_lines.append( GradientLine( ( 50,150 ), ( 50, 300 ),  WHITE, BLACK,  5 ) )

# Main loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    # Paint the window
    window.fill( BLACK )

    # Draw the each of the Gradient Lines
    for line in grad_lines:
        line.draw( window )

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()

